# How Do i Properly execute a for loop?

Tags: java, android

I'm a noob to android and I am trying to populate an arraylist inside a for-loop within an AsyncTask.  I'm trying to take elements from a string array and populate an arraylist of hashmaps.  However i keep getting an ArrayIndexOutofBounds Exception.  I haven't been able to figure out why this is occuring.  Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
JSONArray arr= new JSONArray(s);
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++ ){
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
JSONObject item=arr.getJSONObject(i);

//Getting Comments
String user_comments=item.getString("COMMENTS");
Log.e("usercomment", user_comments); //Returns "~~~1#=#2#=#3#=#4~~~1#=#2#=#3#=#4~~~1#=#2#=#3#=#4"
String[]tokens =  user_comments.split("~~~");
Log.e("token", tokens[0].toString());//Returns "~~~1#=#2#=#3#=#4"
Log.e("token", tokens[1].toString());//Returns "~~~1#=#2#=#3#=#4"
Log.e("token", tokens[2].toString());//Returns "~~~1#=#2#=#3#=#4"
for(int k = 0; k < tokens.length; k++ ){
        String[] one_comment =  tokens[k].split("#=#"); 
        map.put("Avatar", one_comment[0]);//Error thrown here.
        Log.e("Avatar", one_comment[0].toString());
        map.put("Name",one_comment[1] );
        Log.e("Name", one_comment[1].toString());
        map.put("Comment",one_comment[2] );
        Log.e("Comment", one_comment[2].toString());
        map.put("CommentDate",one_comment[3] );
        Log.e("CommentDate", one_comment[3].toString());
           comment_data.add(map);
                                }

                            }
```

Comment: `"~1~2".split("~") eq new String[] { "", "1", "2" } not eq new String[] { "1", "2" }`

Comment: The for loops look correct and none of the counters are being incremented more than once per loop, so my initial guess would be that one of the hard-coded indices is out of bounds, meaning that one_comment doesn't have 4 items, or tokens does not have 3.  Which line is throwing the index out of bounds exception?

Comment: I don't beleive in your comments in the code, `tokens[0]` should be `""`, `tokens[1]` is `1#=#2#=#3#=#4` etc, afaik, delimiter don't included to splitted values

Comment: With your current implementation you can simply make sure `one_comment.length` is the size you expect. If not print to log and figure out what is going wrong. If it is an empty string you can simply skip it

Comment: "I haven't been able to figure out why this is occuring." The first step is to find **where** it is occuring. Which line throws the exception? Please post a stack trace.

Comment: He has a comment next to the second line of the for loop that says the error is being thrown there. But I still agree logcat would be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current implementation, the simplest workaround would be to initialize k at 1.

```
for(int k = 1; k < tokens.length; k++ )...
```

This way you won't be trying to run a blank or null value through your second loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as Selvin states above.

> "~1~2".split("~") eq new String[] { "", "1", "2" } not eq new String[]
>   { "1", "2" }

A way of getting around this is by using a List and removing all the elements in the List which are blank i.e. ""

```
List<String>tokens = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(user_comments.split("~~~")));
    tokens.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
```

Your for loop will be as follows:

```
for(int k = 0; k < tokens.size(); k++ )
   {
    String[] one_comment =  tokens.get(k).split("#=#"); 
    map.put("Avatar", one_comment[0]);
    Log.e("Avatar", one_comment[0].toString());
    map.put("Name",one_comment[1] );
    Log.e("Name", one_comment[1].toString());
    map.put("Comment",one_comment[2] );
    Log.e("Comment", one_comment[2].toString());
    map.put("CommentDate",one_comment[3] );
    Log.e("CommentDate", one_comment[3].toString());
       comment_data.add(map);
   }
```